# Lightweight Rasa NLU server?

Tags: nlp, rasa, rasa-core

I need to train a large model on a desktop, then move access the model to the web to access it in real time on a Linux (Debian) AWS server. All I want to do is extract entities and intents from the model. Is there a a lightweight version that just queries the trained model available, or do I need to install the full Rasa distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question. To my knowledge there is no lightweight version, you'll need to run the full thing :)